# You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server. on centos 32bit / apache 2.2.15

Tags: phpmyadmin

my apache version is 2.2.15 on centos 32bit.
I want to use phpmyadmin but it does not work on my computer..
googled and tried to some solutions but they did not work for me.
Here my phpmyadmin.conf details. 
 please review and help me.

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# cat phpMyAdmin.conf 
<directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
     AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   # Apache 2.4
   <RequireAny>
   Require ip 127.0.0.1
   Require ip ::1
   Require ip 192.168.0.39
   </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   # Apache 2.2
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from All
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Allow from ::1
   Allow from 192.168.0.39
  </IfModule>
  </Directory>
[root@localhost conf.d]#
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?